# Maclaurin polynomial of order 3? Order vs. Degree

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

I am doing some homework and came across a problem that asks:

Find the Maclaurin polynomial of order 3 for f(x) = e^(-4x)

When  did some searching online, all searches came up as "...maclaurin polynomial of degree x. "   So then, is "order" the same as "degree"?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually we use order when we're stressing that it's an approximation to a function: as in "now we expand $f(x)$ to second order".  We use the word degree when we want to stress that the thing we're approximating with is a polynomial: "now we find the degree $2$ Maclaurin polynomial".  Either is fine and everyone will understand what you're talking about.

Comment: To expand on Bye_World's comment, there are plenty of contexts where we might informally use the word "order" to mean something other than degree.  For instance, if I was estimating $(1+x^2)^8$ where $x$ is small, I might call $1+8x^2$ a "first-order approximation", in the sense that it is using the coarsest-grained information about $x$, even though that's not a degree one polynomial.  It's a broader sense of "order" that is more about the sequence of steps you undertake in order to obtain that approximation, rather than the expression itself.